# Bayesian model averaging when none of the models is well specified

Tags: bayesian, model-selection, uncertainty, misspecification, model-averaging

Usually, from what I've read of Bayesian Model Averaging (BMA), a typical assumption is that one of the models is well specified...

However, what will happen when all models are misspecified? What are its implications from a model uncertainty perspective?

Edit:
If I'm uncertain which model is correctly specified, instead of just using one model, I can average along all the models, and probably obtain better predictions than just sticking to one of the misspecified models...  Will it still be able to correct for misspecification if all are misspecified?

Comment: I am not sure I see the connection between both parts, beyond the philosophical.

Comment: @Xi'an If I'm uncertain which model is correctly specified, instead of just using 1 model, I can average along all the models, and probably obtain better predictions than just sticking to one of the misspecified   models...  Will it still be able to correct for misspecification if all are misspecified?

Honestly, I'll take any perl of wisdom on this. =D

Comment: I believe that the average over model will produce asymptotically the average model the closest to the true model...

Comment: @Xi'an thanks for the input. Just before I quit searching, I found out, by chance, the following paper:
http://www.jmlr.org/papers/volume4/clarke03a/clarke03a.pdf

They seem to suggest that in the case where the true DGP is outside the model list, the BMA will converge the single best model of the list, and probably overfit. 

I didn't go into the nitty gritty details, though...